# Get Certificates from current token instead of keystore

Tags: java, digital-signature, x509certificate, keystore

I am getting certificates from the keystore based on alias name using the below code,

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");

Enumeration aliasesEnum = keyStore.aliases();

while(aliasesEnum.hasMoreElements())
{
   aAliasName = (String)aliasesEnum.nextElement();  
   X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)keyStore.getCertificate(aAliasName);
}
```

Here i am getting the certificates which are not there in the token also.

Is there any way to get aliases from the current token instead of getting from keystore?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it suffice for you to check which aliases also have private keys assigned to them?

Comment: I need to get aliases from the current token(smart card) instead of getting from keysore.

Comment: Sorry i did not understand your question, can you please explain me briefly.